# Not running textFieldShouldReturn method

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I just started reading up on Objective-C yesterday, and i can't quite figure why my

```
textFieldShouldReturn
```

method isn't being run.

This is the actual method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.itemTxt.text = @"Return pressed";
    return YES;
}
```

This is the interface line in my header file:

```
@interface ArrViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Comment: Did you set delegate to that textField object?

Comment: is your itemTxt IBOutlet?, If Yes, then set in your interface builder or else add self.itemTxt.delegate = self; in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actively set the delegate for the `UITextField`:

For example, in `viewDidLoad` you could write:

```
myTextField.delegate = self;
```

You can also hook this up in Interface Builder if desired.

Comment: Working as it should. I have to get used to these delegates. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use setDelegate method of your textfield to self